# Type mismatch in Select Case with Variants of subtype Error

Tags: excel, vba

The range indicated in the code below contains a `VLOOKUP` formula. The code is meant to notify the user if `VLOOKUP` returns a `#N/A`.

However, I get a Type Mismatch error on the `Case CVErr(xlErrNA)` line below. Why? How can I fix this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Range("N7:N13,N30:N36,N53:N59,N85:N91,N108:N114,N137:N137")
     Select Case [c]
             Case CVErr(xlErrNA)
                   MsgBox "hello"          
      End Select
  Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Could provide code for `CVErr` and `xlErrNA` variables?

Comment: The given ranges has Vlookup formula which bring the result from another sheet, I want user to add product if vlookup given #N/A error

Comment: Why the `[`square brackets `]` ?

Comment: @lowak `CVErr` is a VBA function like `CStr`, `CInt`, etc.; `xlErrNA` is a constant expression which evaluates to `2042`, representing the `#N/A` error.

Comment: square brackets seem redundant in this case, `c` is already a range which defaults to the `.Value` prperty, which is the same thing that you're "forcing" by evaluating it within the brackets.

Comment: @DavidZemens, thank you for information. Again I am learning something new here in SO :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Variants of subtype Error (as are ouput by `CVErr`) don't like to be compared to any other type. When that happens, a type mismatch is thrown. You will get this error as soon as `c` doesn't contain an error code.

So you have to split your `Select Case` statement in two: one part to deal with error codes, the other to deal with everything else. This works for me:

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("N7:N13,N30:N36,N53:N59,N85:N91,N108:N114,N137:N137")
    If IsError(c.Value) Then
        'Deal with error codes
        Select Case c.Value
            Case CVErr(xlErrNA)
                MsgBox "#N/A"
            Case CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
                MsgBox "Divide by zero."
                'etc.
        End Select
    Else
        'Deal with everything else
        Select Case c.Value
            Case 1
                MsgBox "1"
            Case "a"
                MsgBox "a"
                'etc.
        End Select
    End If
Next c
```